# How to access CommandTarget from ContextMenu Command?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ContextMenu` that suppose to set value on its parent `TextBox`.

[image]

The textbox cannot have a name (by requirement), so I am setting it as `CommandTarget`

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxOne, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Set to 35"
                          Command="{Binding SetAmountCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="35"
                          CommandTarget="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}" />
                <MenuItem Header="Set to 50"
                          Command="{Binding SetAmountCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="50"
                          CommandTarget="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
```

How to access the `TextBox.Text` from inside the Command ?

ViewModel

```
public class MainVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string TextBoxOne { get; set; } = "One";

    private ICommand _setAmountCommand;
    public ICommand SetAmountCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _setAmountCommand ?? (_setAmountCommand = new CommandParameterHandler((o) =>
            {
                object param = o;
                double amount = (double)o;
                //MyParentTextBox.Text = amount; //What to put here ? (Cannot be TextBoxOne = amount, need to route from View)
            }, true));
        }
    }
}
```

Generic CommandParameterHandler

```
public class CommandParameterHandler : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _action;
    private bool _canExecute;
    public CommandParameterHandler(Action<object> action, bool canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `CommandTarget` property is only applicable when the `ICommand` is a `RoutedCommand`, which is not true in your case.

Comment: Why can't you use the binding? Can you please be more specific on that?

Comment: Your `RelativeSource` doesn't work. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550240/contextmenu-command-binding-not-updating-with-the-datasource/19400650#19400650

Comment: What is the purpose of implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and MVVM pattern if you do not notify your view about changes?

Comment: @dymanoid, do you have sample code on RoutedCommand ? I cannot use the binding because the original scenario is way more complex (i.e. a nested ViewModel on ObservableCollection and the ContextMenu was sorted everytime it opens)

Comment: @taquion WADR, it is irrelevant with the question. I need to know how to use CommandTarget to access its parent textbox

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov how to make it work ?

Comment: @JesonMartajaya you need to change your bindings from `RelativeSource` to something depending on `PlacementTarget`, like this `<MenuItem Command="CMD" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget}">`. This makes `CommandTarget` value be bound to an element the menu is open on. If you need `DataContext`, just add one more binding.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov binding changed. Upvoted. How to access the Textbox now ?

Comment: Try this `<MenuItem Command="CMD" CommandTarget="{Binding Source={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget}}, Path=Text">`. From the top of my head so no guarantee. Should not work - let me know, i'll dig my codebase for exact example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days searching for answer, I came across this [RoutedCommand](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/809773/WPF-Routed-Commands-Simplified) tutorial. Yes, you can access `CommandTarget` from `Command`, but it has to be a static `RoutedCommand`. This approach fits the need as `SetAmountCommand` is shared by multiple `MenuItem`.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfCommandTargetDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCommandTargetDemo">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding CanExecute="SetAmountCommand_CanExecute"
                        Command="{x:Static local:CustomRoutedCommand.SetAmountCommand}"
                        Executed="SetAmountCommand_Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxOne, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
            <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Set to 35"
                              Command="{x:Static local:CustomRoutedCommand.SetAmountCommand}"
                              CommandParameter="35"
                              CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget}" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Set to 50"
                              Command="{x:Static local:CustomRoutedCommand.SetAmountCommand}"
                              CommandParameter="50"
                              CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBox.ContextMenu>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

CodeBehind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainVm _mainVm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _mainVm = new MainVm();
        DataContext = _mainVm;
    }

    void SetAmountCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    void SetAmountCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object param = e.Parameter; //CommandParameter
        TextBox textbox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox; //CommandTarget
        if (textbox != null)
        {
            textbox.Text = param.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

`RoutedCommand` has to be `static`, because it is statically bound to XAML element.

```
public static class CustomRoutedCommand
{
    public static readonly RoutedCommand SetAmountCommand = new RoutedCommand();
}
```

For completeness, I cannot have the `Command` on my ViewModel. `SetAmountCommand` property is removed.

```
public class MainVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string TextBoxOne { get; set; } = "One";
}
```

Comment: So you want to handle the logic in the view? Then you don't need to use commands. You might as well handle the Click event of the MenuItem.

Comment: I need the command to be passed from ViewModel, and the MenuItem is generated and sorted dynamically. This command also changes the Text on the view only while keeping the ViewModel property unchanged until next `LostFocus`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass *one* `CommandParameter` to the command. If you want to pass is something in addition to the actual value, you could create a custom composite type that carries more than one value:

```
public class CompositeParameter : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Value), 
        typeof(string), typeof(CompositeParameter));

    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Control),
        typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(CompositeParameter));
    public FrameworkElement Control
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(ControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ControlProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public ICommand SetAmountCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _setAmountCommand ?? (_setAmountCommand = new CommandParameterHandler((o) =>
        {
            CompositeParameter param = o as CompositeParameter;
            if (param != null)
            {
                double amount = Convert.ToDouble(param.Value);
                //...
                TextBox textBox = param.Control as TextBox;
                if (textBox != null)
                    textBox.Text = param.Value;
            }
        }, true));
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxOne, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu.Resources>
                <local:CompositeParameter x:Key="paramA"
                                          Value="35" 
                                          Control="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
                <local:CompositeParameter x:Key="paramB"
                                          Value="50" 
                                          Control="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
            </ContextMenu.Resources>
            <MenuItem Header="Set to 35"
                      Command="{Binding SetAmountCommand}" 
                      CommandParameter="{StaticResource paramA}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Set to 50"
                      Command="{Binding SetAmountCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{StaticResource paramB}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Interesting workaround to pass `CommandTarget` as `CommandParameter`. Thank you.